# Is it possible to have 2 different SSOs (ADs) configured for a group of webapps through KeyCloak?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, keycloak, okta

We have a group of cloud web applications (let's assume 5 java web apps) which are using Okta for SSO through KeyCloak. SAML is used for authentication between webapp and Okta using Keycloak as an Identity broker.

Now customer wants to move to Azure AD from Okta. I have done the POC to connect keycloak to Azure AD and use SAML for authentication between webapps and Azure AD.

But the issue here is that customer also wants to keep some users in Okta for sometime in transition period. So they have the requirement to use Okta and Azure AD both for sometime for SSO for those webapps.

Is it possible to configure Okta as well as Azure AD (basically 2 different Authentication servers/Idps) in Keycloak for the same application and dynamically keycloak decides where it should go for authentication?

Overall I know that its not a good design to have 2 different authentication servers for SSO but customer needs it for transition period.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You can configure multiple IdPs in Keycloak, and also define one of them as the default.

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/server_admin/topics/identity-broker/saml.html